# iPhone - Memory leaks in NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am receiving memory leaks using the following code:

Interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sortedItems;
```

Implementation:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ScannedDate" ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
self.sortedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray]; // memory leak 100% here

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  self.sortedItems = nil;
  [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [sortedItems release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: how sortedItems property is defined? if it has retain property - do you release it in dealloc method?

Comment: How is your property sortedItems defined?

Comment: See updated code for dealloc and definition of sortedItems.

Comment: What is the purpose of the arrayWithArray line?

Comment: Something that compiles completely would help - I guess, you are loosing self.items, as I can see no release about self.items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are creating two unnecessary arrays.

Replace this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
self.sortedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray]; // memory leak 100% here
```

... with this:

```
self.sortedItems = [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Every time you create an array, you send a `retain` to the objects held by the array. If the array is autoreleased (which the convenience methods above do create) then the point at which their `release` messages is sent is uncontrolled by the programmer. This can produce apparent leaks depending on circumstances at runtime.